# my textcontent get erased with each click, how do i keep each clicks value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am little confused on the next step. I am building a calculator, so far I can click each button and each button changes the text content to the desired number. However, it's not storing each number, it just replaces it. Which makes sense but I don't know how to make it store the number. By store I mean display like a normal calculator.

I've had some ideas but again not sure how to implement even with the documentation.

ideas:
for each
for loop

I'd really appreciate some guidance on this, please don't re-write my code as this will not help me, i'm still a beginner using vanilla JS. Ideally I would love something with documentation I can read.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="heading">
    <h1>Calculator!!!!</h1>
</div>

<div class="value-store">

<span id= "number-input" class="starting-point">0</span>
<span id= "increment" class="increment-point"></span>
</div>

<div id="numbers" class="inputs">
    <button id ="seven">7</button>
    <button id="eight">8</button>
    <button id="nine">9</button>
    <button id="multiply">x</button>
    <button id="four">4</button>
    <button id ="five">5</button>
    <button id="six">6</button>
    <button id="minus">-</button>
    <button id="one">1</button>
    <button id="two">2</button>
    <button id ="three">3</button> 
    <button id="add">+</button>   
    <button id="zero">0</button>
    <button id="divide">/</button>
    <button id="equals">=</button>
    <button id="clear">AC</button>
    <button id="del">DEL</button>
</div>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
body {
    font-size: medium;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: bisque;
  
}

h1 {
  font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:darkgreen;
}

.value-store {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border: solid 3px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 500px;
    
    
}

.starting-point {
display: flex;
justify-items: right;

}

.inputs {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border: solid 3px;
    width: 500px;
}



button {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    
}
```

javascript

//display

```
const numbersValue = document.getElementById("numbers");
const operators = document.getElementById("operator")
//let inputValue_span = document.getElementById("user"); 

//buttons with numbers
const buttonZero = document.getElementById("zero");
const buttonOne = document.getElementById("one");
const buttonTwo = document.getElementById("two");
const buttonThree = document.getElementById("three");
const buttonFour = document.getElementById("four");
const buttonFive = document.getElementById("five");
const buttonSix = document.getElementById("six");
const buttonSeven = document.getElementById("seven");
const buttonEight = document.getElementById("eight");
const buttonNine = document.getElementById("nine");

//buttons with operators

const plus = document.getElementById("add");
const minus = document.getElementById("minus");
const divide = document.getElementById("divide");
const equals = document.getElementById("equals");
const multiply = document.getElementById("multiply");


   

//numbers
   
   numbersValue.addEventListener("click", function () {
       
       buttonZero.onclick = function changeNumber() {
           document.getElementById("number-input").textContent = 0;}
       buttonOne.onclick = function changeNumber() {
            document.getElementById("number-input").textContent = 1;} 
        buttonTwo.onclick = function changeNumber() {
            document.getElementById("number-input").textContent = 2;}
        buttonThree.onclick = function changeNumber() {
            document.getElementById("number-input").textContent = 3;}
        buttonFour.onclick = function changeNumber() {
            document.getElementById("number-input").textContent = 4;}
        buttonFive.onclick = function changeNumber() {
            document.getElementById("number-input").textContent = 5;}
        buttonSix.onclick = function changeNumber() {
            document.getElementById("number-input").textContent = 6;}
        buttonSeven.onclick = function changeNumber() {
            document.getElementById("number-input").textContent = 7;}
        buttonEight.onclick = function changeNumber() {
            document.getElementById("number-input").textContent = 8;}
        buttonNine.onclick = function changeNumber() {
            document.getElementById("number-input").textContent = 9;}
    
    }) 
   
//operators
    numbers.addEventListener("click", function () {
      
        plus.onclick = function changeNumber() {
            document.getElementById("number-input").innerHTML = "+";}
        minus.onclick = function changeNumber() {
            document.getElementById("number-input").innerHTML = "-";}
        divide.onclick = function changeNumber() {
            document.getElementById("number-input").innerHTML = "/";}
        equals.onclick = function changeNumber() {
            document.getElementById("number-input").innerHTML = "=";}
        multiply.onclick = function changeNumber() {
            document.getElementById("number-input").innerHTML = "x";}          
                

            
        
     }) 
    
//delete all 

numbers.addEventListener("click", function () {
    
   clear.onclick = function eraseAll () {
       document.getElementById("number-input").innerHTML =0;}
   }) 
   
   //delete one at a time



// show each number pressed
```

Comment: Look at [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append#appending_text) instead of `textContent = `.

Answer (score 0):

in fact when we click on a button in calculator we don't replace the number
you must do real world act

we multiple last number by 10 and add new number to that

so

when you click 4 -> lastnumber is 0 ->0*10+4 = 4

after that click 4 again -> lastnumber is 4 -> 4*10+4 = 44

and ....

or append by string ability -> 4 append to 4 = 44

you can call a function like this :

```
buttonFour.onclick = function changeNumber() {
        document.getElementById("number-input").textContent = getTextValue(4);}
```

and this function is :

```
getTextValue=(data)=>{
  return document.getElementById("number-input").textContent*10+data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Could you put provide me with some documentation please?

Comment: [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/js/)  it's need to practice and get experience . maybe [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/) help you